# Can splitting a one-liner into multiple lines with temporary variables impact performance i.e. by inhibiting some optimizations?

Tags: c++

It is a very general `c++` question. Consider the following two blocks (they do the same thing):

```
v_od=((x-wOut*svd.matrixV().topLeftCorner(p,Q).adjoint()).cwiseAbs2().rowwise().sum()).array().sqrt();
```

and

```
MatrixXd wtemp=(x-wOut*svd.matrixV().topLeftCorner(p,Q).adjoint());
v_od=(wtemp.cwiseAbs2().rowwise().sum()).array().sqrt();
```

Now the first construct *feels* more efficient. But is it true, 
or would the c++ compiler compile them down to the same thing (I'm assuming the compiler is a good one and has all the safe optimization flag turned on. For argument's sake `wtemp` is mild sized, say a matrix with 100k elements all told)?

I know the generic answer to this is 'benchmark it and come back to us' 
but I want a general answer.

Comment: "but I want a general answer." there isn't one, thats why the usual answer to this is 'benchmark it and come back to us'

Comment: I m looking for guidelines on practices to adopt...the whole point is to not have to benchmark every line every time...

Comment: I've edited the title, I hope you don't mind. I think it now sounds much better and precisely asks what you meant. Feel free to reedit back if you don't agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cases where your second expression could be fundamentally less efficient than your first.

The first case is where the writer of the `MatrixXd` class did rvalue reference to this overloads on `cwiseAbs2()`.  In the first code, the value we call the method on is a temporary, in the second it is **not**.  We can fix this by simply changing the second expression to:

```
v_od=(std::move(wtemp).cwiseAbs2().rowwise().sum()).array().sqrt();
```

which casts `wtemp` into an rvalue reference, and basically tells `cwiseAbs2()` that the matrix it is being called on can be reused as scratch space.  This only matters **if** the writers of the `MatrixXd` class implemented this particular feature.

The second possible way it could be fundamentally slower is if the writers of the `MatrixXd` class used expression templates for pretty much every operation listed.  This technique builds the parse tree of the operations, and only finalizes all of them when you assign the result to a value at the end.

Some expression templates are written to handle being able to be stored in an intermediate object like this:

```
auto&& wtemp=(x-wOut*svd.matrixV().topLeftCorner(p,Q).adjoint());
v_od=(std::move(wtemp).cwiseAbs2().rowwise().sum()).array().sqrt();
```

where the first stores the expression template `wtemp` rather than evaluating it into a matrix, and the second line consumes the first intermediate result.  Other expression template implementations break horribly if you try to do something like the above.

Expression templates are also something that the matrix class writers would have to have specifically implemented.  And is again a somewhat obscure technique -- it would mainly be of use in situations where extending a buffer is done by seemingly cheap operations, like string append.

Barring those two cases, any difference in performance is going to be purely "noise" -- there would be no reason, a priori, to expect the compiler to be confused by one or the other more or less.

And both of these are relatively advanced/modern techniques.

Neither of them will be implemented "by the compiler" without explicitly being done by the library writer.

Comment: Thanks for having taken the time to explain things so pedagogically...all answers are good but this one relies on specific explanations and not general principles.

Comment: @user189035 ahem: "I want a general answer".  This _is_ a good answer though

Comment: @Baldrickk: sorry I should have been more carefull in ny use of words. I meant 'general' in a different sense in my comment above than in my question. In my comment above, I meant 'general principle' such as 'readability is more important than performance'...which while true is only a maxim that don t address (I feel) my specific question. In contrast, the points in this answer explain more precisely why in this instance it shouldn t matter (I can check for example whether the two cases are true or not in the library I am using).

Answer (score 2):

In general second case is much more readable, and that's why preferred. It clearly names temporary variable, that helps to understand code better. Moreover, it's much easier to debug! That's why I would strongly recommend to go for second option.

I would not care much about preformance difference: I think good compiler will make identical code from both examples.

Comment: Thanks...but would you expect a performance hit, or as Borgleader commented, 'there is just no way to know. Ever'

Comment: personally:Readability and mainterance is more important.On typical compiler,would expect absolutely no difference.On an ancient or buggy compiler,I'd expect **no noticeable** difference.Some per hit could show up if I use some of the temporaries like `wtemp` later in the code. When I need to make sure that I will not refer to them later, I sometimes inject some extra `{}`: `int foo = 5, bar = 4; {int tmp = foo; foo=bar; bar=tmp;} zomg(foo,bar);`. It looks strange, but sometimes helps. With their scope heavily limited,that's almost like temporaries, compiler can even reuse their stack space.

Answer (score 2):

The most important aspects of code in order, most important -> less important:

1. Correct code
2. Readable code
3. Fast code

Of course, this can change (i.e. on embedded devices where you have to squeeze out every last bit of performance in limited memory space) but this is the general case.

Therefor, you want the code that is easier to read over a possibly neglible performance increase.

I wouldn't expect a performance hit for storing temporaries - at least not in the general case. In fact, in some cases you can expect it to be faster, i.e. caching the result of `strlen()` when working with c_strings (as the first example that comes to mind)

Once you have written the code, verified that it is correct code, *and* found a performace problem, only then should you worry about profiling and making it faster, at which point you'll probably find that having more maintainable / readable code actually helps you isolate the problem.